# Date SELECT does not return all available values

Tags: sql-server, date, select

I have been trying to call out all available dates from the last 3 months but unfortunately my "formula" seems to always leave out 1 day.

For example, if today is the 23-03-2023 and I want to return all the dates from the last 3 months I would expect to see everything from the 23-12-2022 but also INCLUDING the 23rd of December.

What I am doing is returning everything starting from today's date -3 months (so from the 24th of December) and excludes always today's date.

My database is on a SQL Server 2016.

```
select * from TABLE where DATE_COLUMN >= dateadd(month, -3, getdate())
```

Comment: You have to account for the "off-by-one" error; either use "yesterday" for the start date, or subtract one day from the 3-month result.

Comment: This isn't an off-by-one issue. This code is comparing datetime values with different time components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the time part from `GetDate()` before filtering:

```
select * from TABLE where DATE_COLUMN >= dateadd(month, -3, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Comment: Thank you a million times! This exact line has solved my issue !

Answer (score 1):

Use `cast(dateadd(month, -3, getdate()) as date)` to convert the filter value to a `date` without a time part.

`GetDate()` returns the current date *and* time. When you compare a `datetime` to a `date`, both are treated as `datetime` values, ie with a date component. `2023-12-31 01:00` will always be later than `2023-12-31` so all entries up to that time will be lost.

You can also use `cast(GetDate() as date)`. `DATEADD` doesn't really care. Pick the expression that's easier to read.

To exclude today's date you still need to cast to a `date`. :

```
where DATE_COLUMN >=cast(dateadd(month, -3, getdate())) and 
      DATE_COLUMN < cast(getdate() as date)
```

**What about `cast(someDateTime as date)='2023-03-20'` ?**

This would produce the correct results but have bad performance. If this was a non-date type, it would be *very* bad performance because the query engine wouldn't be able to use any indexes covering `someDateTime`. It would have to calculate the cast result for every single row and *then* filter them. This is called a non-SARGable query or, less scientifically, a Row-By-Agonizing-Row (RBAR).

With date types, SQL Server will convert this into a date range query, equivalent to :

```
WHERE someDateTime >='2023-03-20' and someDateTime <'2023-03-21'
```

While this can use indexes, it can't use the statistics gathered for the actual stored dates so the server can still end up with a bad execution plan. If, for example, almost all rows pass the criteria using an index would be a waste of time. The server would have no way of knowing this though and would still use the index.

This is discussed at great length at [Cast to date is sargable but is it a good idea?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34047/cast-to-date-is-sargable-but-is-it-a-good-idea).

The solution in this case is to write the range expression explicitly:

```
WHERE someDateTime >=@dateParam and someDateTime <DATEADD(d,1,@dateParam)
```

Comment: Using what table, data, indexes and execution plan? Without indexes, it's full table scans all the way.

Comment: If you're already 100x slower than you should, does it matter? You should be fixing the query and the table instead. You're optimizing the wrong thing. I won't race a horse I *know* has a lame foot. That would be cruel to all involved - the database, the disk, and the horse

Comment: Thank you everyone! Your responses have helped me a lot in solving my problem. I took into consideration the initial suggestion and it has solved the issue!